# (Java Noob) Having trouble with a double type

Tags: java

I'm doing an exercise and i have to create certain object with some values.
I have a class "Comprador"

```
public class Comprador extends Persona {

    double presupuesto;

    public Comprador(String nombre, String apellido, String numeroDocumento, double presupuesto) {
        super(nombre, apellido, numeroDocumento);
        this.presupuesto = 00;
    }

    public double getPresupuesto() {
        return presupuesto;
    }

    public void setPresupuesto(double presupuesto) {
        this.presupuesto = presupuesto;
    }

    @
    Override
    public String toString() {
        return "nombre=" + nombre + ", apellido=" + apellido + ", numeroDocumento=" + numeroDocumento + "Comprador{" + "presupuesto=" + presupuesto + '}';
    }
}
```

The idea is to build a "Comprador" object and then inform those values, but when it comes to the double I always get "0.0".

```
Comprador monica = new Comprador("Monica","Robes","304", 3532.2);
System.out.println(monica.toString());
```

I tried to initialize the double, but no results there. I know that it probably is something stupid but i can't figure it out.

Comment: You aren't using the `presupuesto` parameter to your constructor, but instead are always setting the member variable to `0`.  If you want it to be non-zero, use the value from the constructor, or call its setter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the line `this.presupuesto = 00;` in your constructor, which causes your problem.

Replace it with

```
this.presupuesto = presupuesto;
```

and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't user the "presupuesto" var, check the constructor on line 2. you are set 00 value.

```
public class Comprador extends Persona {

double presupuesto;

public Comprador(String nombre, String apellido, String numeroDocumento, double presupuesto) {
    super(nombre, apellido, numeroDocumento);
    this.presupuesto = presupuesto;
}

public double getPresupuesto() {
    return presupuesto;
}

public void setPresupuesto(double presupuesto) {
    this.presupuesto = presupuesto;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return  "nombre=" + nombre + ", apellido=" + apellido + ", numeroDocumento=" + numeroDocumento + "Comprador{" + "presupuesto=" + presupuesto + '}';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor, the member variable `presupuesto` is never initialized with the parameter value of the constructor.

Change this `this.presupuesto = 00;` by this `this.presupuesto = presupuesto;`